# Change value of a variable in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, openmp

So, im trying to change the value of threads in openMP using ***OMP_NUM_THREADS***. When i type ***export OMP_NUM_THREADS=value*** in prompt it works fine, it changes the number of threads, but when i try to do this in a makefile it doesn't work. My makefile:

```
run:
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
./cowichan_openmp vecdiff >> out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, that every line is executed in a new subshell.
Also see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Execution).

You may try:

`run: export OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
  ./cowichan_openmp vecdiff >> out`

or as in another answer:

`run:
  OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./cowichan_openmp vecdiff >> out`

Comment: Hi, if it helped you, please accept the answer :) thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Each line of the recipe is run in a separate shell. So in this case, you're running one shell, setting `OMP_NUM_THREADS`, then exiting that shell and running another one (without that variable).

You can just put the variable definition and the call to `cowichan_openmp` on the same line:

```
run:
  OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./cowichan_openmp vecdiff >> out
```